# Local mail exchange with DNS servers

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, bind, internal-dns

I have a problem with correctly setting up a working infrastructure for testing mail spoof preventing mechanisms.
As stated in a graph below, I have 2 mail servers (centos1 & 2) and 2 DNS servers. It is obligatory to have one DNS per host to test SPF records.

The problem is, that two DNS cannot communicate with each other. I mean, they can ping but I do not really know how to set up them to provide A or MX records for other domain.
In real networks those local DNS servers have to communicate to root DNS that provides domain names to the local ones. Should I set up additional root DNS server? If so, how to do it? I have looked almost everywhere on the internet and found nothing...

For example, I want to send an email from xyz@example.local to zyx@another.local, but when I do so, mail exchange demon shows up a following message:

```
<xyz@another.local>: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for
    name=another.local type=A: Host not found
```

My present configuration for one DNS is (the second one is just like that with only difference in domain name):

Forward zone:

```
$TTL 1D
@       IN SOA  dns1.example.local. root.example.local. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
@       IN      NS      dns1.example.local.
@       IN      A       192.168.21.131
dns1    IN      A       192.168.21.131
host    IN      A       192.168.21.131
centos1 IN      A       192.168.21.128
centos2 IN      A       192.168.21.129
another.local   IN      A       192.168.21.130
example.local   IN      MX 5    centos1.example.local.
```

Reverse zone:

```
$TTL 1D
@       IN SOA  dns1.example.local. root.example.local. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
@       IN      NS      dns1.example.local.
@       IN      PTR     example.local.
dns1    IN      A       192.168.21.131
host    IN      A       192.168.21.131
centos1 IN      A       192.168.21.128
centos2 IN      A       192.168.21.129
131     IN      PTR     dns1.example.local.
128     IN      PTR     centos1.example.local.
129     IN      PTR     centos2.another.local.
```

And named.conf

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1;192.168.21.131; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { localhost; any; };

        /*
         - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
         - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
           recursion.
         - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access
           control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
           cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification
           attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
           reduce such attack surface
        */
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

zone "example.local" IN {
        type master;
        file "forward.example.local";
        allow-update {none; };
};

zone "21.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "reverse.example.local";
        allow-update {none; };
};


include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

To sum up, how to make my mail servers able to exchange mails with one DNS for every one of them?
Please be sure to check the graph below, I think it can explain a lot.

[network graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKlND.png)

Looking forward to hearing from you! :D

Comment: Did you really use `.local` TLD or is this just bad obfuscation. `.local` is reserved for multicast DNS, you shouldn't use it for "real" zones.

Comment: It is changed now, but as long as I understand, it has no impact on my project since it is all done in my local network without connecting to external networks. I just want to configure 2 mail servers, each with its own domain to later implement spf, dkim and dmarc mail security. If I am wrong I am sorry but this is my first adventure with dns servers.

Comment: Are you asking where to add the glue records? (I do not see why you would be running *two* name servers at all for your test. Either simulate a typical setup - different nameservers for the tld and each domain, or just exclude DNS from your test and point them to a single instance that has all the records.)

Comment: It is a project which you run on VMware Workstation thus I vote to close as it does not belong here on ServerFault. That being said, it seems like you are in way over your head. First learn how DNS works, then how to set up and configure name servers. Then learn about mail servers and how they interact and use the DNS. I believe your understanding of DNS is a major issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have incorect record here :

```
another.local   IN      A       192.168.21.130
```

Your zone is for domain/hostname : `example.local`

If you want to add new domain with : `another.local`

Create new zone for it.